# App Engine local environment shows incorrect data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Just started using Google Cloud SDK Shell after using the older, gui-based, version.  I have multiple projects under development, if that matters.
Here's what I do

```
run gcloud SDK shell (click on the icon!)
cd \myproject
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

In the browser (Chrome),

browse to http://localhost:8000/datastore

Under Datastore Viewer, I see 'tables' from a completely different project 
(say, myotherproject)

Under Datastore Indexes, I see 'indexes' from the correct project (myproject)

Under Task Queues, I see the correct queues listed (I have specified different queues setup for parts of myproject)

Everything works fine for myotherproject.  So, is there something I am missing to get the Datastore Viewer to show the correct 'tables'?

Many thanks, David

Edit: no matter what project I run, Datastore Viewer shows the same data (from myotherproject) but Datastore Indexes show the correct indexes.

Edit: Windows 8.1, Python v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1

Edit: further questions 1) does gcloud sdk use a different datastore from the original app engine sdk?  2) if so, where is it by default or do I have to define it upfront?

Comment: I am attempting to replicate this issue but I remain unsuccessful. 

Can you please provide more information in regards to the version of Python that you are using? This is because Datastore interactions in [Python 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_local_datastore) are different from [Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#using_the_local_development_server_with_google_cloud_services).

Comment: The dev_appserver  does not support development of Python 3 apps on [Windows](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#local-dev-server).

Comment: Can you also verify that you have cleared the local datastore as specified in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server?csw=1#clearing_the_local_datastore)? 
Can you try on Firefox and Internet Explorer as well as try using Chrome in an Incognito window? If at all possible, it could be a good idea to try reproducing this on another machine. This will allow us to rule out any local caching that may be present.

Comment: @JKleinne - which datastore should I clear?  I have 20 appengine.projectname folders in local temp.  In every case, Datastore Viewer shows 'tables' from project 1, while Index Viewer shows indexes from the currently running project.

Comment: This still sounds like a local (caching) issue. 
1- Is this behaviour reproducible on ANY 2 projects that you choose among the 20 you mentioned?
2- Is it OK to assume that you are [explicitly specifying the Datastore path](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#Python%202_Changing_local_datastore_location)?
3- What happens if you run [“dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes app.yaml” command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#clearing_the_local_datastore)?

Comment: @JKleinne - 1) all projects see the same dataset, 2) no, I am not specifying the datastore path, the documentation, which you indicate, indicates that this is optional, is it not?  3) I have not tried the --clear_datastore yet as I don't want to risk the loss of (test) data although if gcloud uses different datastores to app engine I have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their help with this.  It appears GCloud uses one datastore for all projects so the --datastore_path is not really optional when you have multiple paths.  However, I kept getting errors with --datastore_path so I went with the following...

```
dev_appserver.py --storage_path=c:\gcdata\projectname app.yaml
```

Yes, could have been c:\temp but this gives me separate 'databases', one for each project.

Note also that GCloud SDK does not use the same data as the original App Engine SDK grrrrrr!